# Django Annotate Count

Tags: python, django, django-models, annotations

Could someone help me to understand why func Count calculates 1 for the actor that does not have any publicated scene?:

```
actors = Actor.objects.filter(state=Actor.State.PUBLISHED)\
    .annotate(scenes_cnt=Count('scenes', filter=Q(state=Scene.State.PUBLISHED)))
```

I have one actor who has only one scene with state=Scene.State.PREVIEW but the code above calculates scenes_cnt=1 for this actor. I'm confused. Thanks in advance!

I try to calculate publicated scenes for actors. Expect to get scenes_cnt=0 if actor does not have any scene with state=Actor.State.PUBLISHED

Comment: What result do you get when you do only `filter ` without `count`?

Comment: Double check Scene.State.PREVIEW and Scene.State.PUBLISHED are not the same value.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the abstract model for models that have State field:

```
class StatedModel(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        abstract = True
    class State(models.TextChoices):
        PREVIEW = 'PR'
        COMMING = 'CM'
        PUBLISHED = 'PB'    
    state = models.CharField(max_length=2, choices=State.choices, default=State.PREVIEW)
```

Comment: Can you please edit the original question rather than putting additional information in answer boxes?

Comment: Can you please edit the original question rather than putting additional information in answer boxes?

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I got for different requests:

```
scenes = Scene.objects.filter(actors__id=331).values('id')
>>> [{"id": 444}]

scenes = Scene.objects.filter(actors__id=331, state=Scene.State.PUBLISHED).values('id')
>>> []

actors = Actor.objects.filter(id=331).annotate(scenes_cnt=Count('scenes', filter=Q(state=Scene.State.PUBLISHED))).values('id', 'scenes_cnt')
>>> [{"id": 331, "scenes_cnt": 1}]

actors = Actor.objects.filter(id=331, scenes__state=Scene.State.PUBLISHED).values('id', 'scenes__id')
>>> []

actors = Actor.objects.filter(id=331, scenes__state=Scene.State.PREVIEW).values('id', 'scenes__id')
>>> [{"id": 331, "scenes__id": 444}]
```

So, the main question why scenes_cnt = 1 ??